# react-leaflet-control - TypeError: (0 , _reactLeaflet.withLeaflet) is not a function

Tags: react-leaflet

Not sure why suddenly the custom Control is not working in my react-leaflet map application. The error occurs during "import the 'Control' from 'react-leaflet-control'" statement.

[image]
It used to work a few weeks back, since then it was not allowing me to import the 'Control' component. The only change we did was we upgraded the react-leaflet' package to 2.2.0 and nothing else.

Currently I am using react-leaflet-control^1.4.1. It is obvious that this is not compatible/supported to work with react-leaflet-control^2.2.0.  I tried downgrading to 1.9.1 by looking into my old package.json file, but still the same issue. I tried removing all the node-module and tried npm install to update all packages, but still the same issue.

Anyone has idea on what exactly is wrong here, is there any dependency I need to install to overcome this?

Thanks and Regards,
~Paul

Answer (score 1):

Anything to do with the change recently? i.e instead of downgrading `react-leaflet`, upgrade `react-leaflet-control`. After an upgrade of `react-leaflet`, the plugins fails to load first time. Therefore, the developers have fixed it. It could be this that is causing the issue.

[Here's example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7p2xr4w4z).

where the relevant javascript code is

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import Control from "react-leaflet-control";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Map zoom={13} center={[53.8008, -1.5491]}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <Control position="topright">
        <div className="so">Top Right Control</div>
      </Control>
    </Map>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Related [github issue](https://github.com/LiveBy/react-leaflet-control/commit/810512fc62d713a02bc58684265effa9647b6968)

Comment: Hi Layik, I have tried upgrading and tried your options as well.  My map component is in a different directory and I am I don't have any components inside my app.js file.  What I tried now was to create a whole new custom component (dummy react dom) and imported that component and implemented reducers actions and able to achieve it.  Not sure what the hell is wrong with the control.js file which is coming from node_modules.  Seems it is not supporting the .WithLeaflet method with the latest version.

Comment: Feel free to share a snippet so I can try and help. Can you adapt the example in the sandbox?